# Can you recommend me book with problems?

Tags: books

I am searching for book about algorithms (excercises) with solutions. Can you recommend me one?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [The Art of Computer Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) from [Donald Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth).

Next to the complex problems it describes, it offers various tasks on very different levels. It even scales their hardness between 10 (trivial task) and 50 (currently unsolved problems until now).

Comment: thanks for proposition. Are there solution to the task in this book ?

Comment: @M.Swe Yes, at the end it has the solutions (of course not for the unsolved ones :-) ).